# Scala Logging: is LazyLogging blocking or non-blocking?

Tags: scala

I recently read [this](https://manuel.bernhardt.io/2016/08/31/akka-anti-patterns-logging-the-wrong-way/) article that makes me wonder whether using `LazyLogging` would create a performance bottleneck.

My question: is [Scala Logging](https://github.com/lightbend/scala-logging)'s [`LazyLogging`](https://github.com/lightbend/scala-logging/blob/d271c40599bd6cc4dcee35b90768506f50b26e33/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/scalalogging/Logging.scala) trait blocking or non-blocking?

We log and process a lot of messages and use Akka. So does having just lazy loggers help or hurt when it comes to performance?

Comment: scala-logging is not related to Akka, btw, they are different libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scala-logging library relies on the [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) library, which is an API frontend for various logging libraries. Therefore, whether logging is synchronous or not is completely defined by the actual logging framework that you use. The most prominent and modern ones are [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch) and [Log4J 2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), but there are other, usually older alternatives, like [commons-logging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/), [log4j1](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) or even [java.util.Logging](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) (JUL).

So, depending on your backend configuration, your log invocations might be either synchronous or not. For example, Logback has [AsyncAppender](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#AsyncAppender) which acts as an asynchronous frontend for other, potentially blocking appenders; it is also possible for specific appenders to be async as well, e.g. if it is an appender which writes to an external logging aggregation system.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does this affect the latency significantly? Using  AsyncAppender  over synchronous ones? Also are there any drawbacks using AsyncAppender?

Comment: That's pretty much explained in that documentation page - asynchronicity implies potential issues with flushing and also with overloading the processing queue. There is no universal answer - if it is critical for your application not to block even on logs, and your output sinks for logs can be blocking in synchronous mode (e.g. network socket, slow disk, etc), then you most likely have to use some kind of async appender. Otherwise, you'll have to benchmark and find whether it is okay for your application to block on logging statements or not.